# How to get JQuery closest input id and data-attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple input fields in my form that use the Add button. I have created my button with an image tag. Each image tag has the same class. Once I click on the image I want to get the id of my closest input field as well as data attribute value. Here is example of my HTML:

```
<div class="formItem">
    <label for="status">Status:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ls_status" id="ls_status" value="" data-master="STATUS" size="10" maxlength="10" readonly />
    <img src="Images/add.png" alt="Click to add value" class="masterRecords" />
</div>
<div class="formItem">
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ls_age" id="ls_age" value="" data-master="AGE" size="10" maxlength="10" readonly />
    <img src="Images/add.png" alt="Click to add value" class="masterRecords" />
</div>
```

Here is what I tried in JQuery:

```
$('.masterRecords').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('input').prop('id'));
});
```

In my debugging console I see `'undefined'` only. First of all I'm not sure if I approached the best way to solve this problem. I repeat there is multiple elements that use the same class and I need to pull ID and data for each of them. They are all in separate div containers as you can see in my example above. If anyone see where is bug in my code please let me know. Also I would like to hear some suggestions if there is better way to do this with JQuery/HTML5/CSS3. Thank you.

Comment: You need `prev()`. `closest()` looks for closest **ancestor**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<INPUT/>` element is not an ancestor of your image.  Try:

```
$('.masterRecords').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).closest(".formItem").find('input').attr('id')); 
});
```

Comment: What is better solution to use closest div class or use .prev() ? Is there any difference in efficiency?

Comment: I doubt it makes any difference.  Every single approach, including the two others in responses here, ultimately has to go through the work of traversing up the DOM, finding a parent, and then finding the input tag in its children.  The code varies, but the tactic is identical.

Comment: @XavierJ What about overall approach for this problem? Would you recommend something different? Is there any potential problem that can happen in this case?

Comment: Nope, you're right on track.  Stick with what you're doing.  It's the same as I'd do

Answer (score 2):

Try using `siblings` instead of `closest`.

```js
$('.masterRecords').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).siblings('input').prop('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formItem">
    <label for="status">Status:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ls_status" id="ls_status" value="" data-master="STATUS" size="10" maxlength="10" readonly />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo01e.png" alt="Click to add value" class="masterRecords" />
</div>
<div class="formItem">
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ls_age" id="ls_age" value="" data-master="AGE" size="10" maxlength="10" readonly />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo01e.png" alt="Click to add value" class="masterRecords" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jdjc1bc7/

```
$('.masterRecords').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).siblings('input').prop('id'));
});
```

You can check for input in siblings, since in your current DOM the inputs are sibling to the element which is being clicked.

This should be the fastest way for you. https://jsperf.com/jquery-siblings-vs-parent-find-vs-find

Answer (score 1):

If your structure will always be like this, you could also retrieve your related input with

```
$('input', $(this).parent())
```

which will return all inputs in the same div as the image

Answer (score 1):

Because input is to the left of  you can find it like this:

```
$('.masterRecords').on('click', function(){
   console.log($(this).prev('input').prop('id'));
  });
```

If input was after button then you can find it like this:

```
 $('.masterRecords').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).next('input').prop('id'));
 });
```

Then for data attribute value just use .data or .attr of ID value you  get:

```
 $('#'+ID).attr('data-master');
```

```js
$('.masterRecords').on('click', function(){
var inputTextId = $(this).prev('input').prop('id');

  console.log(inputTextId);
    console.log($('#'+inputTextId).attr('data-master'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formItem">
    <label for="status">Status:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ls_status" id="ls_status" value="" data-master="STATUS" size="10" maxlength="10" readonly />
    <img src="Images/add.png" alt="Click to add value" class="masterRecords" />
</div>
<div class="formItem">
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ls_age" id="ls_age" value="" data-master="AGE" size="10" maxlength="10" readonly />
    <img src="Images/add.png" alt="Click to add value" class="masterRecords" />
</div>
```